# How to save multiple images with a hasMany relationship in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-2.x

How can I save multiple images in the secondary table?

My first table is `Car`, which has the fields:

- id
- title
- featured_image and

My secondary table is `Gallery`, which has the fields:

- id
- car_id
- gallery_images

**Model Car.php**

```
class Car extends AppModel
{
    var $name='Car';
    var $hasOne = array(
        'Gallery' => array('className' => 'Gallery',
            'foreignKey' => 'car_id'
        ));
}
```

**Model Gallery.php**

```
class Gallery extends AppModel
{
    var $name='Gallery';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Car' => array('className' => 'Car',
            'foreignKey' => 'car_id',

        )
    );
}
```

**CarController.php**

```
$this->Car->saveAll($this->data)
```

Comment: Please clarify what is field `gallery_images` and what data type it holds. Where do you plan to store the file names for the images?

Comment: gallery_images is a field name of gallery table which hold the image name and data type is varchar and my plan

Answer (score 0):

To save multiple images associated to a car, first you have to modify your Car model to:

```
class Car extends AppModel
{
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Gallery' => array(
            'className' => 'Gallery',
            'foreignKey' => 'car_id'
        ));
}
```

or just

```
class Car extends AppModel
{
    var $hasMany = array('Gallery'); //simplified version, as fields follow convention
}
```

Then you have to structure you data as follows:

```
$data = array(
    'Car' => array('title' => 'Volvo'),
    'Gallery' => array(
        array('gallery_images' => '/path/image1'),
        array('gallery_images' => '/path/image1'),
        array('gallery_images' => '/path/image3'),
    ),
);
```

In your view, the form should have the following structure:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Car', array('action' => 'add'));
echo $this->Form->input('Car.title');
echo $this->Form->input('Gallery.0.gallery_images');
echo $this->Form->input('Gallery.1.gallery_images');
echo $this->Form->input('Gallery.2.gallery_images');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

In your `CarControllers::add()` you can save all four records (one car and three images) with:

```
$this->Car->saveAll($this->request->data);
```

Please consider renaming your fields to represent better your data. For example, `gallery_images` should be renamed to something like `image_filename`, and model `Gallery` to `Image` of `Photo`.

As per `Car.featured_image`, it can hold a foreign key for galleries, or you can move this field on to the galleries/images table and make it a field named `type` (holding 'featured, normal, etc'), or perhaps a boolean named `is_featured`.